# Change volume of individual speaker

Tags: headphones, speakers, sound-volume

My headphones are a bit damaged it seems and the left has higher volume than the right. It isn't my ears, the song or the device :). Is there a program to change just one speaker's volume? Lion allows you to set the balance, but I don't think this is the same thing - it would lead to the sound shifting into the left speaker, effectively reducing the stereo effect. Windows 7 can do this, but I'm not quite that desperate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Balancing changes the volume of both speakers at the same time.

**Since it only changes the volume, there is not manipulation of the stereo effect (sound shifting).**

For example: If you play a track that plays on the left speaker and then shift the balance to the very right - you will not hear anything. If you play a stereo track, you will only hear the right track in the same case. This can be very easily verified using this [this sample track](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e8ODm-F9-IM).